# How to get a density plot per category with ggplot2 or python?

Tags: d3.js, ggplot2, plotly, bokeh, seaborn

Departing from this dataset (R code):

```
test = data.table(categories = rep(c('a','b'), each = 100), 
                  values = c(rnorm(100,mean = 0,sd = 1), rnorm(100, 10, 2)))
```

I'm trying to get a density plot per category. This is the final output I would need:

[image]

How do you call those kind of plots?, I don't know how to search for them in google.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're referring to a [joyplot](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DE8kWJkXoAIYzgS.jpg:large). They can be made with the R package `ggjoy`.